# How to exclude files from protractor suite?

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor configuration with suites.

I am trying to configure a suite to run all files but one...

Is there a way a to do that? right now I have a long list of all the tests I do want to run, but it would be much nice to have it run 'everything but ..' instead.

I tried something like this:

```
mySuite: ['**/*.ptor.js', '!**/excludeThis.ptor.js']
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the `exclude` option in config file? pls refer this link - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L211

Comment: @RamPasala couldn't find a way to define it for specific suite. However, now that I think about it, the configuration is just javascript... I can use a library like glob to get an array of files...

Comment: Yes, exactly. glob libraries would definitely help you out deal with such scenarios!